# Fetching data from three different tables but it is duplicating records

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch data from two different table , but in real three table are involved.

```
tbl_prosubcategory         procategories             product
ID    Pkey                   ID  Pkey                ID  (P Key)
Cat_id Fkey from category    Categorytype            Cat_id (FKey)
subcatname                                           subcat_id(fkey from prosubcategory) 
                                                     productname
                                                     qty
```

I am selecting product key from product table with following query . I have go only one record but it return me 5 duplicate records due to 5record from subcategory  against that same category .

```
SELECT c.categoriestype AS categoryname, s.SubCatName AS subcategoryname, p.productname AS productname, p.productprice AS productprice, p.id AS proid, p.productimage AS productimage, p.productthumbnail AS productthumbnail
FROM tbl_ProCategories c, tbl_ProSubCategories s, tbl_products p
WHERE p.subcat_id = s.cat_id
AND p.cat_id = c.id
AND c.id = s.cat_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: It would be a great help if some one could solve this problem Thanks

Comment: Do you have some data samples?

Comment: categoryname  subcategoryname  productname  productprice  proid  productimage  productthumbnail <br/> 
Makeup  Eye Shadow  MUA Pearl Eye Shadow  200  2  ProductImage/Original_product_img1.png  ProductImage/product_img1__Thumb.png<br/>
Makeup  Eye Shadow Primer  MUA Pearl Eye Shadow  200  2  ProductImage/Original_product_img1.png  ProductImage/product_img1__Thumb.png<br/>
Makeup  Eye Liner  MUA Pearl Eye Shadow  200  2  ProductImage/Original_product_img1.png  ProductImage/product_img1__Thumb.png<br/>
Makeup  Eye Lash  MUA Pearl Eye Shadow  200  2  ProductImage/Original_product_img

Comment: how can i make date more readable and indented

Comment: @user3034453 can't do that in comment. post in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

one product belongs to 5 sub-category, and you are retrieving subCateName(different each other), so 5 results is happen, I think removal SubCatName from projection and use `DISTINCT` can help you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  c.categoriestype AS categoryname, 
  p.productname AS productname, p.productprice AS productprice,
  p.id AS proid, p.productimage AS productimage,
  p.productthumbnail AS productthumbnail
FROM tbl_ProCategories c, tbl_ProSubCategories s, tbl_products p
WHERE p.subcat_id = s.cat_id
AND p.cat_id = c.id
AND c.id = s.cat_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: @user3034453 good to see you! and not forget accepting my answer ;-)